# how to remove rows from data-frame where fields containing only dash/hyphen(-) ,without affecting the negative values in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a data set containing eg:

```
A      B     C
---- ----- -----
a      -     0
b      -16   2
c      -     2
```

I want to remove rows with only dash(-),expected output is:

```
A   B   c
--- --- ---
a    nan  0
b    -16  2
c    nan  2
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: You want to ignore the `-----------------` line?

Comment: I just edited the question.I want to remove rows with fields containing (-).

Comment: @Toto I tired using df1[df1.columns[1]].map(lambda x:re.sub("[^0-9.]","",x)) and replace method,both are changing the negative values as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes `-`only when not followed by a digit:

```
re.sub(r'-(?!\d)', 'nan', s)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this  worked perfectly for my problem.

Comment: only problem is, when number comes with $ sign or % this regular expression is not enough.

Comment: @ann: Could you give some examples with extra sign and expected result?

Comment: if there are any special characters only in a field then it should be replace with np.nan and any special characters associated with a number for eg: $40 should be read as 40., 45% should be read as 45.

Comment: @ann: As far as I understand, you have to run 2 regex, the second one can be: `re.sub('[^\d-]+(\d+)\D+', \1)` it will remove non digit or dot before a number and non digit after a number by nothing, keep only the digits. Tell me if it works and I'll add in the answer.

Comment: This is not working,this will remove the negative sign of a negative value.
First answer will work when there is only - as special character. when there are other special characters like %,$,# etc then we can combine @AkshayNevrekar's answer-replace("-",np.nan) along with ("[^0-9.-]", "", x)  this re.

Comment: @ann: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55099913/edit) and add more test cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pandas` and `numpy`, you can do it using.

```
df = df.replace("-", np.nan)
```

Output:

```
A    B    c

a    NaN  0
b    -16  2
c    NaN  2
```

Comment: thank you.This is also working, but for my scenario i preferred regular expression.